# ExecuteNonQuery() doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql-server

Every time I try to run my code, I get this exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Tried multiple workarounds, but I never get past the `ExectueNonQuery` line. Can someone tell me what's wrong with it?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=CHARLIE-PC\MSSQLSERVER1;Initial Catalog=Tema;Integrated Security=True;");
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Fisier (idFisier, Nume, idFolder) VALUES ('"+idFis.Text+ "','"+ numeFis.Text + "','" +idFoldFis.Text +"',)", con);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Use SQL Parameters always rather than gluing text together like that which is very error prone and dangerous

Comment: One of the strings you're stuffing in there probably has a paren. Don't concatenate SQL strings, for this reason among many others. Use `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue`.

Comment: While this has a major SQL injection risk... The error you are seeing is because you have an extra comma before the close parentheses.

Comment: @EdPlunkett [Can we please stop using `AddWithValue()`, already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @Siyual Good point.

Answer (score 4):

While the other questions state the root problem, your trailing comma, you really must do better about your queries. Do not glue your query together like that, use parameters instead. [If you do not you are opening yourself to huge security problems](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25684/how-can-i-explain-sql-injection-without-technical-jargon). Also you really must put the connection in a `using` statement so when a error does happen the connection will still be closed.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=CHARLIE-PC\MSSQLSERVER1;Initial Catalog=Tema;Integrated Security=True;"))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Fisier (idFisier, Nume, idFolder) VALUES (@idFis,@numeFis,@idFoldFis)",con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@idFis", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1).Value = idFis.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@numeFis", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1).Value = numeFis.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@idFoldFis", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1).Value = idFoldFis.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jonesopolis yes, but the only reason it is is because it inherits from `Component`. There is no resources freed other than some internal caches that get nulled out when you dispose of the class.

Comment: [Its the same thing as `Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270681(v=vs.110).aspx), that is disposable too but you rarely see anyone ever do that (in fact it even has a comment in the remarks section saying it is unnecessary). The only time you ever need to dispose of a command is when you are using it in a designer as a component or you have code that subscribes to it's `Disposed` event.

Comment: @Jonesopolis [here is the source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlCommand.cs,53ad9885e5a8fc48), the only thing it does is null out `_cachedMetaData` and the only thing the `base.Dispose(disposing)` call does is `site.Container.Remove(this);` (for when you are using it as a designer component) and firing the `Disposed` event.

Answer (score 4):

The comma is your problem, but I would recommend a few other changes at least before moving on:

1. Don't embed your connection strings into each db connection request. Use app.config/web.config or anything else :)
2. Ensure your connections are commands are properly disposed of
3. Parameterize any SQL queries to prevent injection attacks
4. Abstract database commands into separate business layer

**1. Utilize an "app.config" for connection strings**

There are many docs out there on keeping a connection string secure, but at a minimum, don't embed straight into each of your connection code.

Add an "app.config" to your client project (or utilize the web.config of web projects). At a minimum, this looks like this:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
      <add key="db" value="Data Source=CHARLIE-PC\MSSQLSERVER1;Initial Catalog=Tema;Integrated Security=True;" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Then add a reference to "System.Configuration" to your project, and you can reference it like this in your code:

```
var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["db"]);
```

**2. Ensure your connections ard commands are properly disposed**

Wrap connections and commands in `using`. Here is an example:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["db"]))
{
    con.Open();
    var sql = "/* My command here */";
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
    {
        // SQL execution here
    }
} // Closing is now handled for you (even if errors occur)
```

**3. Parameterize any SQL queries to prevent injection attacks**

Concatenating strings are very dangerous for SQL commands (just google "SQL Injection"). This is how to protect yourself.

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["db"]))
{
    con.Open();
    var sql = "INSERT INTO Fisier (idFisier, Nume, idFolder) VALUES (@idFisier, @nume, @idFolder)";
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@idFisier", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = idFis.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@nume", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = numeFis.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@idFolder", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = idFoldFis.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
} // Closing is now handled for you (even if errors occur)
```

**4. Abstract database commands into separate business layer**

It is usually best practice and will save you many headaches by writing separate classes (even class library) as your business layer that only contain your data commands. Then your UI would only handle calling the business layer methods.

If your database ever changes or you need to do similar functionality in other parts of your UI, it won't be very fun updating the same query all over your UI as opposed to just updating a single spot in your business layer.

Answer (score 3):

Make SQL being *readable* and *parametrized* and you'll find the routine easy to implement:

```
// Extract a method (or even a class): do not mix UI and business logic/storage
// Just RDBMS logic: no UI controls or something at all
private static void CoreInsertFisier(string idFisier, nume, idFolder) {
  // Do not hardcode the connection string, but read it (from settings)
  // wrap IDisposable into using
  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringHere)) {
    con.Open();

    // Make sql readable (use verbatim strings @"...")
    // Make sql parameterized 
    string sql = 
      @"INSERT INTO Fisier (
           idFisier, 
           Nume, 
           idFolder)
        VALUES (
           @prm_idFisier, 
           @prm_Nume, 
           @prm_idFolder)";

     // wrap IDisposable into using
     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con)) {
       // Parameters.Add(...) is a better choice, but you have to know fields' types
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_idFisier", idFisier); 
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_Nume", nume);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_idFolder", idFolder); 

       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
     }
  }
}
...

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // UI: just one call - please insert these three textbox into db
  CoreInsertFisier(idFis.Text, numeFis.Text, idFoldFis.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra trailing comma:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=CHARLIE-PC\MSSQLSERVER1;Initial Catalog=Tema;Integrated Security=True;");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Fisier (idFisier, Nume, idFolder) VALUES ('"+idFis.Text+ "','"+ numeFis.Text + "','" +idFoldFis.Text +"')",con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
```

Anyway as others said, it is a very bad idea to concatenate your query that way, since it could lead you to have sql injection on your code.

Comment: Good catch, but I wish you wouldn't encourage him to concatenate the SQL like that (or not discourage him, I guess is a better way to put it).

Comment: I can't in good conscious do anything other than downvote this. Sql injection is just awful and offering code examples where it is wide open is horrible.

Comment: @SeanLange I understand your point. But the OP had a specific problem to be solved. Everyone on this question had made it clear that apart from solving this comma issue, he should rethink how he is approaching to the solution. I don´t see the need to downvote that. This isn´t a refactor forum. Or at least the question didn´t asked for that.

Comment: @NicoRiff true but continuing to show people how not to code is bad. It takes so little to turn that sql injection vulnerable code into a parameterized query. Keep in mind that the OP likely does not have a lot of experience so they will take your example and use it. If you really want to help them, take the extra two minutes to turn this disastrous example into a parameterized query example. It would take less effort to show an example of it done right then arguing about why we shouldn't help them.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the , before the closing )

```
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Fisier (idFisier, Nume, idFolder) VALUES ('"+idFis.Text+ "','"+ numeFis.Text + "','" +idFoldFis.Text +"')",con);
```

Comment: Correct for the question as asked, but to the poster, please do NOT do this.  going this route is asking for your database to be wiped/hijacked/etc.